# Order By Date when the Date is converted to MM/DD/YY

Tags: sql, database, sql-order-by

I have a query (in pseudo) language like this .

```
SELECT * FROM TMP
(
SELECT 
NAME , 
Format([CREATE_DATE],"dd/mm/yyyy") AS CREATE_DATE
FROM 
TABLE 
)TMP
ORDER BY CREATE_DATE
```

CREATE_DATE is stored in the DB in DD/MM/YY/HH/SS/MS format .

The inner table already loses the time stamp since we are converting to DD/MM/YY . 
Now what I have a bunch of records of the same date .

The question is will the result always be same if we query this again and again and we have say over 5000 records ? The Order By just has many records of the same date , hence my question . The real records however have time stamp  which gets truncated after the first query .

I think its possible to actually ask this question is a more simplified manner .
Supose we have a n number of records with the same Value and I do a ORDER BY over the same value , will SQL show the same result all the time ? Does it arrange by the PRIMARY_IDN in any case to make sure results are in the same order ?

Very specifically speaking , we have had a issue with related to such a query and reported in **ORACLE** but not in **SQL** , could that have any signifance ?  That is probably its a bit random(*I am scared to used this word*) in ORACLE while SQL isn't in this particular context?  I am just trying to understand .

Comment: Just wanted to know this in a general scenario . To be very specific we have an issue related to possible this ORDERING in Oracle . SQL has never reported any issue any thoughts ? Maybe SQL has a defaulted way of sorting and Oracle could be random - random as in we dont know :-) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT <columns that you want> FROM
(
SELECT 
NAME , 
Format([CREATE_DATE],"dd/mm/yyyy") AS CREATE_DATE, create_date as orig_createDate
FROM 
TABLE 
)TMP
ORDER BY orig_create_date
```

That is, just pass in the original date from the subquery and use it for ordering.  You don't have to include it in the output.

Your final question is about a sort being "stable".  That is, when rows have the same value will they be ordered in the same order.  The answer is no.  Databases generally do not guarantee that `order by` use a stable sorting algorithm.  So they rows could be in a different order.

Comment: Thanks thats indeed interesting . I will look into that , however would the DB show random ordering for same values in my case ? Any thoughts ?

Comment: you're not sure of what's happening internally. Hard drive blocks order may influence the results, and these are not 100% of being always the same.

Comment: I think we take things for granted :-) While we should realize CPU just does the same job all over again !